# win32-x64 binaries cannot be used on the 'linux-x64' platform

Tags: node.js, sharp

*'win32-x64' binaries cannot be used on the 'linux-x64' platform* got this error while installing node sharp on windows system. This is breaking my lambda code on aws while execution.

Comment: Tried npm uninstall sharp and then install again, still getting the same issue

Comment: Installed sharp using **ubuntu** zipped it, still got error */var/task/node_modules/sharp/build/Release/../../vendor/lib/libvips-cpp.so.42: file too short*

Comment: **package.json** `{
  "name": "resize",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "image resizer",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Ankit",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "serverless-plugin-tracing": "^2.0.0",
    "sharp": "^0.23.4"
  }
}`

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  I can sorta understand the error message, but no idea how to work around it on AWS.

Comment: Did you people solve the problem? I am facing the same issue

Comment: Still running into it. Says delete node_modules/sharp...